# How to use a variable from within inner class without declaring it final

Tags: android

I am developing an application which uses Estimote beacons and I have a problem regarding a variable I need to use within a class.
So in my case I will need to retain an actual beacon and the previous one and compare if they are neighbours in my adjacency matrix.
The thing is that I cannot make this possible about the previous beacon as if I declare it final I cannot modify it during my beacon scanner operation. Either if I don't make it final android studio will not allow me to use it within inner class. Do you have a solution for this problem?

Code:

```
beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1000,3000);
         int previousBeaconInMatrix = 0;


        beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {





            public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> list) {
                if (!list.isEmpty())
                {

                    Animation animate =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.test);

                    int sizeOfList = list.size();


                        int  actualBeacon = findMyposition(list.get(0));



                        if(adjacencyMatrix[actualBeacon][previousBeacon] == 1) {
                        if (beaconTable.containsKey(number)) {


                            List<Integer> coordinates = new ArrayList<Integer>(2);
                            coordinates = beaconTable.get(number);
                            View myPosition = ButtonTable.get(coordinates);
                        blueButton.clearAnimation();
                        blueButton2.clearAnimation();
                        yellowButton.clearAnimation();
                        orangeButton.clearAnimation();
                        orangeButton2.clearAnimation();
                        purpleButton.clearAnimation();
                        redButton.clearAnimation();
                        greenButton.clearAnimation();
                            myPosition.startAnimation(animate);
                        }

                        } 


                 previousBeacon = actualBeacon ; 

   }
    }
       });
    region = new Region("ranged region", null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: What is the variable you are referring to, is it `previousBeaconInMatrix`? And is the inner class in question the `new BeaconManager.RangingListener()`? Finally, what is the name of the class where this code is in? The easiest might be to make that class to implement `BeaconManager.RangingListener` and then you can access `previousBeaconInMatrix` from the `onBeaconsDiscovered` method of that class.

Comment: You could extend `BeaconManager.RangingListener` to add the fields that you need to change

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use a variable that changes its value across inner classes is to move from a variable to a private attribute in the outer class.